# hexadecimal array to binary array

Tags: python, binary, hex

I want to convert this hexadecimal array :

```
[7,3,2,0,1,9,0,4]
```

into this one

```
[0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
```

where you can recognize the first 4 integers is egal to 7 in binary format (0111), and so on.

I tried to use `format(x, '04b')` but the result is in string format :

```
['0111','0011','0010','0000','0001','1001','0000','0100']
```

Consequently I can't use the result as binary array. How to do that ?

Comment: One way would be `list(map(int,list(''.join(a))))` where `a` is your current result but it seems a bit ugly.

Comment: Actually, my first approach could be shortened to `list(map(int,''.join(a)))`

Comment: What makes `[7,3,2,0,1,9,0,4]` a hexadecimal array? It looks like it only contains decimal integers.

Comment: @usr2564301: I know that. I'm asking the OP why they're calling it a hexadecimal array.

Comment: @usr2564301: I believe all integers are binary in computers. What's in the OP question appears to me to be decimal representation of an "array" of them. Let's stop talking about this topic, it's boring.

Answer (score 1):

This one liner will return a list of integers as you want:

```
hex = [7,3,2,0,1,9,0,4]
list(map(int,"".join([format(x, '04b') for x in hex])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitwise operations:

```
h = [7,3,2,0,1,9,0,4]
[i >> b & 1 for i in h for b in range(3, -1, -1)]
```

This returns:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [7,3,2,0,1,9,0,4]

hexa = ''.join(str(e) for e in arr)

print(bin(int(hexa,16))[2:])
```

This takes a hexidecimal array and converts it into binary!

Comment: you and exchange print for x =  then, use x.split() to separate it into an array

Comment: But it returns a string, and the OP wants a list of integers.